# Sort by size in an array of arrays with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to order by size, however, I don't understand why it doesn't work. Apparently the error must come from the "for in" since when testing it I can't iterate "products" completely.

```
let products = [
  [
    { product: "t1", price: 123, size: "S" },
    { product: "f1", price: 45, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t5", price: 910, size: "M" }
  ],
  [
    { product: "f2", price: 6.78, size: "L" },
    { product: "t2", price: 910, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t3", price: 910, size: "S" }
  ]
];

let obj = {
  sizesSM: [],
  sizesLXL: []
};

for (let i in products)
  for (let j in products) {
    if (products[i][j].size === "S" || products[i][j].size === "M")
      obj.sizesSM.push(products[i][j]);
    else 
      obj.sizesLXL.push(products[i][j]);
  }

console.log(obj);
```

The expected output is to save all sizes S and M on one side, and L and XL on the other in the object.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can fill your sizesSM like this :

```
obj.sizesSM = products.flat().filter(product => product.size === "S" || product.size === "M")
```

You can adapt for the other array

Ps: By the way your inner loop is looping on the wrong array, it should loop on an inner array also

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
for (let j in products) {
```

with

```
for (let j in products[i]) {
```

and it will work.

```js
let products = [
  [
    { product: "t1", price: 123, size: "S" },
    { product: "f1", price: 45, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t5", price: 910, size: "M" }
  ],
  [
    { product: "f2", price: 6.78, size: "L" },
    { product: "t2", price: 910, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t3", price: 910, size: "S" }
  ]
];

let obj = {
  sizesSM: [],
  sizesLXL: []
};

for (let i in products)
  for (let j in products[i]) {
    if (products[i][j].size === "S" || products[i][j].size === "M")
      obj.sizesSM.push(products[i][j]);
    else 
      obj.sizesLXL.push(products[i][j]);
  }

console.log(obj);
```

---

In addition to *forloop*, you can also use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve.

```js
let products = [
  [
    { product: "t1", price: 123, size: "S" },
    { product: "f1", price: 45, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t5", price: 910, size: "M" }
  ],
  [
    { product: "f2", price: 6.78, size: "L" },
    { product: "t2", price: 910, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t3", price: 910, size: "S" }
  ]
];

const sizeGroupBy = (...size) => 
  products.flatMap(a => a).filter(o => size.includes(o.size));

console.log('sizesSM', JSON.stringify(sizeGroupBy('S', 'M')));
console.log('sizesLXL', JSON.stringify(sizeGroupBy('L', 'XL')));

const restructure = arr => 
  arr.flat().reduce((accumu, current) => {
    if(['S', 'M'].includes(current.size)) {
       accumu['sizesSM'] = 
        [...accumu['sizesSM'] ?? '', current];
    }
    if(['L', 'XL'].includes(current.size)) {
       accumu['sizesLXL'] = 
        [...accumu['sizesLXL'] ?? '', current];
    }
    return accumu;
  }, {});
  
const obj = restructure(products);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use the `for in` statement with an array.

Basically `for in` is used to iterate over an object.

You can use the `for of` statement or `forEach` method on arrays...

```js
let products = [
  [
    { product: "t1", price: 123, size: "S" },
    { product: "f1", price: 45, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t5", price: 910, size: "M" }
  ],
  [
    { product: "f2", price: 6.78, size: "L" },
    { product: "t2", price: 910, size: "XL" },
    { product: "t3", price: 910, size: "S" }
  ]
];

let obj = {
  sizesSM: [],
  sizesLXL: []
};

products.flat().forEach(product => {
    if (product.size === 'S' || product.size === 'M') {
      obj.sizesSM.push(product)
    } else {
      obj.sizesLXL.push(product)
    }
})

console.log(obj);
```